# SSH connection not working

Tags: 20.04, bash, ssh, openssh, aws

I created an EC2 instance (ubuntu 20.04), after successfully creating this instance I SSH into it and ran some commands which were basically to install some open source tools as sudo user, but once I logout from this session and try to login back again it won't allow me to SSH into the same instance, can someone help me with this issue. Please feel free to ask for more details if I was not clear.

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@IP
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Comment: can you run with -v (verbose) and paste output like so: `ssh -v -i "key.pem" ubuntu@IP`. You might want to censor personal information before pasting, but that should give enough information to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Also what tools did you install as sudo user? and how did you ssh into it the last time (also with a private key, or with password?)